# ios - Google maps in webview not loading current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, webview

I have created a webview with html in it to load current users location.

Here is structure used:

webview.m - loads index.html

index.html - shows the data

info.plist - NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription & NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription added

Here is two situations:

1) If I load Google Maps in Webview - it does not loads my current location. The spinner just goes spinning and showing map of the world.

2) In index.html I am adding the code to load my current location longitude and latitude. In browser of laptop(not xcode) it shows my location if I open index.html in xcode it does not shows me it.

Probably there is something to add for allowing the app to get your location, e.g. on browser it asks for permission for location. In app it does not asking me that.

Here is the code:
webview.m

```
#import "Webview.h"

@interface Webview ()

@end

@implementation Webview

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    NSString *urlAddress= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demos/index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];

    [_webView setDelegate:self];
    _webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
    _webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true;
    _webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
   [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];





}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

index.html

loading google maps

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://maps.google.com/" />
```

loading current location

```
  <p>Address:
        <div id="address"></div>
         <div id="l"></div>
         <div id="lo"></div>
    </p>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var currgeocoder;

    //Set geo location lat and long
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position, html5Error) {
        geo_loc = processGeolocationResult(position);
        currLatLong = geo_loc.split(",");
        initializeCurrent(currLatLong[0], currLatLong[1]);
    });

    //Get geo location result
    function processGeolocationResult(position) {
        html5Lat = position.coords.latitude; //Get latitude
        html5Lon = position.coords.longitude; //Get longitude
        html5TimeStamp = position.timestamp; //Get timestamp
        html5Accuracy = position.coords.accuracy; //Get accuracy in meters
        return (html5Lat).toFixed(8) + ", " + (html5Lon).toFixed(8);
    }

    //Check value is present or
    function initializeCurrent(latcurr, longcurr) {
        currgeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        console.log(latcurr + "-- ######## --" + longcurr);

        if (latcurr != '' && longcurr != '') {
            //call google api function
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latcurr, longcurr);
            return getCurrentAddress(myLatlng);
        }
    }

    //Get current address
    function getCurrentAddress(location) {
        currgeocoder.geocode({
            'location': location
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results[0]);
                $("#address").html(results[0].formatted_address);
                $("#l").html(html5Lat);
                $("#lo").html(html5Lon);   

            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
});
    </script>
```

info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription </key>
    <string>Give us permission to use your location</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your message goes here</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Question: how to enable my app to ask the permission for location? or to load the location straightaway?

Answer (score 0):

**Question: how to enable my app to ask the permission for location? or to load the location straightaway?**

First of, here's an [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980150/embedding-google-maps-in-uiwebview-without-asking-for-location-permissions-and-s) that might offer the solution on displaying maps using UIWebView.

Now with regard to permissions in iOS Maps:

Try to enable the permission by using `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:)`. This means you are giving the user permission while using the app.

```
extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
      mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
      mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
  }

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {

      mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

     locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

  }
}
```

For the full tutorial kindly [check this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutoria).